# how to integrate electrical currents in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I could solve the following problem in PHP, but I wonder if it could be done in SQLite.

The simplified version looks like this: I have a simple electrical circuit. I can switch on and off a red, a green and a blue light independently. I record the timing in seconds and electrical current in ampere for each light in a table as follows:

```
| Lamp  | On | Off | Current |
|-------|----|:---:|--------:|
| red   | 2  |  14 |       3 |
| green | 5  |  8  |       8 |
| blue  | 6  |  10 |       2 |
```

As you can see, they overlap. If I want to integrate the current properly (to calculate the energy consumption), I have to transform this table to a new one, which adds the electrical currents. I get the following table (manually) with adapted timing:

```
| T1 | T2 | Sum(Current) |     Comment    |
|:--:|:--:|-------------:|:--------------:|
|  2 |  5 |            3 |       red      |
|  5 |  6 |           11 |    red+green   |
|  6 |  8 |           13 | red+green+blue |
|  8 | 10 |            5 |    red+blue    |
| 10 | 14 |            3 |       red      |
```

Any ideas if sqlite can do that? Perhaps by creating interim tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly complex, but I was able to do it with a couple of views:

```
create table elec (lamp char(10),on_tm int,off_tm int,current int);

insert into elec values 
('red',2,14,3),
('green',5,8,8),
('blue',6,10,2);

create view all_tms as 
select distinct on_tm
  from elec
 union 
select distinct off_tm
  from elec;

create view all_periods as
select t1.on_tm,
       (select min(t2.on_tm)
          from all_tms t2
         where t2.on_tm > t1.on_tm) off_tm
  from all_tms t1

select 
  all_periods.on_tm,
  all_periods.off_tm,
  sum(case when elec.on_tm <= all_periods.on_tm
            and elec.off_tm >= all_periods.off_tm
      then elec.current
      else 0
      end) total_current,
    group_concat(case when elec.on_tm <= all_periods.on_tm
                   and elec.off_tm >= all_periods.off_tm
     then elec.lamp
     end) lamps
from 
  all_periods,
  elec
group by
  all_periods.on_tm,
  all_periods.off_tm
```

The views combine all of the start/stop times into distinct blocks as you have in your output (2-5,5-6, etc.).

The final SELECT evaluates each row from the original table against each time block.  If the lamp was on (start time is before the start of the evaluation time, and stop time is after the end of the evaluation time), then its current is counted.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes a [sufficiently recent SQLite version](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html); with earlier versions, you would have to replace the [common table expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) with temporary [views](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html):

```
WITH all_times(T)
AS (SELECT "On" FROM MyTable
    UNION
    SELECT Off  FROM MyTable),
intervals(T1, T2)
AS (SELECT T,
           (SELECT min(T)
            FROM all_times AS next_time
            WHERE next_time.T > all_times.T) AS T2
    FROM all_times
    WHERE T2 IS NOT NULL)
SELECT T1,
       T2,
       (SELECT sum(Current)
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE T1 >= "On" AND T2 <= Off) AS Current_Sum,
       (SELECT group_concat(lamp, '+')
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE T1 >= "On" AND T2 <= Off) AS Comment
FROM intervals
ORDER BY T1
```